# TransientObjectException: save the transient instance before flushing

Tags: hibernate, jpa, jpa-2.0

I'm currently working on a project and I've encountered this error:

```
org.hibernate.TransientObjectException: object references an unsaved transient instance – save the transient instance before flushing
```

What happened:
1.) I have a session scope variable that I set after login, let's say SessionScopeVariableA.

2.) Then I have a page where I'm adding an entity, let's say EntityA.

3.) EntityA has a lazy field sessionScopeVariableA, so when I invoke the add method I have to set this variable.

```
entityA.setSessionScopeVariableA(sessionScopeVariableA);
em.persist(entityA);
```

4.) Note that SessionScopeVariableA is wrap in a session scope producer while the action is conversation scope.

5.) Whatever I do, I always end up with the transient error specified above.

Any idea?

Comment: is sessionScopeVariableA mapped as an entity too ?

Comment: Yes, the app is a multi-tenant 1 so during login, the user who signin needs to select what tenant he has to work and that will be save in the session scope.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What solved this problem was managing the connection resource with CDI using solder. This is how we did this:

//qualifier for the tenant

```
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Target({ ElementType.METHOD, ElementType.FIELD, ElementType.PARAMETER, ElementType.TYPE })
public @interface CurrentTenant { }

//producer for the current tenant
@Produces
@Named("currentTenant")
@CurrentTenant
public Provider getCurrentTenant() { //.. }
```

//in a separate util class, define how you want to manage the connection resource (cdi)

```
@ExtensionManaged
@ConversationScoped
@Produces
@PersistenceUnit(unitName="myEM")
@MyEMJpa
private EntityManagerFactory em;
```

//interface for the connection resource

```
@Qualifier
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Target({ ElementType.METHOD, ElementType.FIELD, ElementType.PARAMETER, ElementType.TYPE })
public @interface MyEMJpa { }
```

//inject entity manager in your service

```
@Inject
@MyEMJpa
protected EntityManager em;
```

//How to inject the current tenant

```
@Inject
@CurrentTenant
private Provider currentTenant;
```